# Make text bold as user types in javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, autocomplete

I've implemented an auto-completion list in javascript so that if User types 'a', all names starting with 'a' are displayed in drop-down menu. Now I want to make the text bold depending on user input in the drop down menu. So if user types 'ab', the letters 'ab' should appear bold in drop-down menu containing the word about.

Here is some part of my JS code where I'm displaying the names:

```
document.getElementById('dropmenu').style.visibility='visible';
var element = document.createElement("div");
var namecontainer = document.createElement("div");
namecontainer.setAttribute('id', "name" + div_id);
namecontainer.className = "namecontainerclass";
element.setAttribute('id', "div" + div_id);
element.className = "elementclass";
var text = document.createTextNode(myArray[i].name);

element.appendChild(text);

document.getElementById('dropmenu').appendChild(namecontainer);


document.getElementById("name" + div_id).appendChild(element);

var img=document.createElement("img");



img.setAttribute("src", myArray[i].image);
img.setAttribute("width", 25);
img.setAttribute("height", 25);

namecontainer.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: Why are you recreating the wheel and not using a script out there that does this already? Plus we can not help you fix your code without seeing any of what you have written.

Comment: I'm learning Javascript so it's just a sample function to help me get the hang of things.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that came up my mind. You want to check the user-input against the name (myArray[i].name), at that point create some `textnodes` (or an `element` if it matches), and append those to the container element (a `div` in this case). I didn't test it, but it is a bit pseudocode to show how to handle this higlighting without using any javascript framework.

```
// searchString is the string entered by the user...
// split by the searchString, but group the selection so the matches 
// also get added to the result array.

var match = new RegExp('\\('+ searchString +')\\',"gi");

var textParts = myArray[i].name.split(match);
var nodes = [];
var element = document.createElement("div");

// only create elements for names that actually match.
// if there is only one match, there wasn't a match by the split 
if (textParts.length > 1){
  for(i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++){
     if (textParts[i] == searchString) {
       nodes[i] = document.createElement("em");
       nodes[i].createTextNode(searchString);
     } else {
       nodes[i] = document.createTextNode(textparts[i]));
     }
     element.appendChild(nodes[i]);
  }

}
```